# How to set default save location for an image?

Tags: image, path

Currently, when I have a rendered image (or any other kind of image) I want to save, the file browser always insists on starting the save location from my Documents folder.

I would prefer to set a default location for the file browser to start from, so that I don't need to navigate to the appropriate folder before saving.

I have already attempted to set this in "Preferences" by modifying the "Render Output" filepath to point to the desired folder. The file browser is able to 'see' this location (I'm able to open it up from the file path), so the path is clearly valid. However, setting this property doesn't seem to do anything at all, as far as I can tell.

I've also attempted to create a new Blend file, save a render to the desired folder, and then save the start-up file. This also doesn't do anything to the file navigator's behavior.

Please note that I am not referring to where animation frames are saved by default- I am aware this is under the Output Properties panel. Rather, I want to specify a default save location for the file explorer to start from when saving a render.

Comment: I can confirm that the path in the Render Output settings in the preferences are being ignored, for me it starts at // (which I don't mind, so I never considered that to be a bug). I tried relative and absolute, no difference. It might be worth reporting that.

Comment: Blender 2.83.3?

Comment: This hardcoded path is coming from `BKE_appdir_folder_default` which is also used by the file browser. From what I can see there's currently no option to change this.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to figure this one out? I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding, or if this might have to do with some kind of computer file storage settings or compatibility error. You may have tried this already; But after doing the usual render action:
**Render Image (f12)> Save As**

In the file explorer I click the "Create New Directory" folder icon and then from then on it always renders to that folder, for the project you're working on. If you have multiple projects that you would like to keep saving to the same folder, it should usually keep it the same.

[image: Save As]

[image: New Directory]

[image: New Folder Directory]

[image: New Location]